# Difference between these 'split' use

Tags: ruby

I would like to understand the difference between these two expressions:

The first one, which works:

```
def sum_difference_product
  a, b = gets.split.map { |num| num.to_i }
  puts a + b
  puts a - b
  puts a * b
end
```

and

```
def sum_difference_product
  a = gets.split.map { |e| e.to_i  }
  b = gets.split.map { |e| e.to_i  }
  puts a + b
  puts a - b
  puts a * b
end
```

which returns:

```
NameError:

NoMethodError:
   undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: How do you provide the input?

Comment: @Stefan: good point, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one contains two calls to `gets`, which requires STDIN to contain two lines of input (however you do it, via user input in console or piping data to the script). If it doesn't, you get errors.

Answer (score 0):

## First

```
def sum_difference_product
  a , b = gets.split.map { |num| num.to_i }
  puts a + b
  puts a - b
  puts a * b
end
```

here `a, b = gets.split.map { |num| num.to_i }` will grab the standard entry, split it by any space character into an array, cast each element into integers, and put it in a and b.

result => if in your standard entry you type `22 12`, your array will be `['22', '12']`, and then after the map `[22, 12]`, then `a = 22` and `b = 12`.

At this point you can do your operations. `a + b == 34` here

---

## Second

```
def sum_difference_product
  a = gets.split.map { |e| e.to_i  }
  b = gets.split.map { |e| e.to_i  }
  puts a + b
  puts a - b
  puts a * b
end
```

same here, `gets.split.map { |e| e.to_i  }` will return an array, and and put it in a if your standard entry is well formatted of numbers separated by spaces

b will wait for a second standard entry, and will be an array too.
a + b will concatenate the 2 arrays.

---

If in your standard entry in the first method you send `22 12` then `a == 22` and `b == 12`.

If you send the same standard entry in the first gets of the second method, then `a == [22, 12]`. If you don't send any data in the second gets of the second method, then gets will return nil, and you can't call split on nil. This is your error.